# showing python list in HTML got object HTML span element

Tags: javascript, python, html

i work on program that can make auto report, i want to show a list on html table but i got stuck how to make it work like i want, im using flask as framework here. i have a python code like this:

```
a = 5
b = 2
result = []
subtraction = a - b
result.append("the value is "+str(subtraction)+" point")
```

then the `result` sended to index.html, on my html the code is like this :

```
<table><tr>
<td>No</td>
<td>description</td>
<td><span id="result"></span></td>
</tr></table>
<script>
var result = '{{result}}';
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

i expect to get result value like `the value is 3 point`but i get`object HTML SpanELement`, i already check the console.log, i got `&#34;the value is 3 point&#34;` as `result`value. how can i make it work the way i want ? sorry if my question is not clear, I will edit again. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `alert({{result}})` to see what you get? if it is json consider using JSON.parse({{result}});

Comment: What are you using to send `result` to the template?  Flask?

Comment: yes, im using flask

Comment: i tried using alert and JSON.parse, both make the table column didnt show anything @A.Meshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what templating system you are using.  Here is one for Flask:

```
{% for item in result %}
  <td><span>{{ item }}</span></td>
{% endfor %}
```

This is way more efficient than using javascript to build the document.  And this will loop through the list.

**BONUS:** F-strings in Python 3 will change your life:

```
result.append(f"the value is {subtraction} point")
```

Comment: @GAEfann sorry i wrote my code wrongly, ill edit it first

Comment: i tried it multiple time but it won't work in my case

Comment: You're going to have to share more code and the error messages.  This is the correct way to do this task.

Comment: aaah my bad, i got typo, your solution is work, thanks so much @GAEfan

Comment: i combine it with your first solution